# Determine $\lambda^{2}(\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{2}: x \in \mathbb Q\cap [0,1], y \in [0,1]\})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Define $M:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{2}: x \in \mathbb Q\cap [0,1], y \in [0,1]\}$

Find $\lambda^{2}(M)$

Ideas:

Well, first I should show that $M \in \mathcal{B}^2$

Note that for $x  \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$

$\{x\}\times[0,1]\in\mathcal{B}^2$

And so it follows: $(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1])\times[0,1]=\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]}\{x\}\times[0,1]$ which is $\in \mathcal{B}^2$

Now onto $\lambda^{2}(M)$:

As proven above:

$\lambda^{2}(M)=\lambda^{2}(\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]}\{x\}\times[0,1])=\sum_{x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]}\lambda^{2}(\{x\}\times[0,1])$

I assume that $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ is a hyperplane but I lack any idea to show that it is a hyperplane. Is $\dim (\{x\}\times[0,1])=1$ or $2$?

**Secondly**, out of interest's sake, if I have $A \in \mathcal{B}^{2}$, with $\lambda^{2}(A)=c,$ where $c \in \mathbb R_{>0}$

what can I say about $\lambda(A)$ as well as $\lambda^{3}(A)$?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

I assume $\lambda^{3}(A)=0$ as $A=A\times \{0\}\in \mathcal{B}^3$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^{3}$, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ is ***not*** a hyperplane, but rather a subset of the hyperplane $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ in $\Bbb R^2$. The dimension of $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ is $1$.

Regarding the second part (I'm assuming that $\lambda^n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$), if $\lambda^n(A) >0$ then we have $\lambda^m(A)=0$ for all $m>n$ 
 because $A$ would be contained in a hyperplane of $\Bbb R^m$
.

On the other hand, $\lambda^r(A)$ doesn't really make sense if $r<n$ because $A$ is an object in $\Bbb R^n$ which is not contained in $\Bbb R^r$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification: Is $\{x\}\times \mathbb R$ a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^{2}$ because $\dim \mathbb R=1$ and $(x,0)+\mathbb R=\{x\}\times \mathbb R$?

Comment: Basically yes, but note that in your expression $(x,0)+\mathbb R$ here $\Bbb R$ should be identified with $\{ (0,y): y\in\Bbb R \}$.